# Sunspot rails: include associated models when calling .results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, model-associations, sunspot-rails

Let's say that I want to search for Events in my app.
When I display the results, I want to display who created the event, for instance.

Is there any way to add `.includes(:user)` somewhere, to avoid unnecessary queries (one for each event)? I can't find it in the doc.
Should I just index the user name with the event? But I'd have to keep the user info up to date...

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found the answer, it was actually quite simple:

```
Event.search(:include => [:user]) do...
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an updated answer, if We need to include an nested association

Then use this

```
Event.search(:include => {:user => :city})
```

In this case it will include user and his associated city

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need to add a normal and nested include, here's what I needed:

```
Professional.search(include: [:user, {branches: [:business]}]) do
```