# Sunspot rails: include associated models when calling .results and how to correct syntax for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr, sunspot

A similar question has already been asked

[Sunspot rails: include associated models when calling .results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282344/sunspot-rails-include-associated-models-when-calling-results)

```
search = Sunspot.search(ArticlePost, Post, User, Group) do
   fulltext query
   with(:api_search_shared, true)
   paginate :page => page, :per_page => 100
end
```

what i want to do is include a few other tables with the query something like that:

```
include [{:user => [:user_job_title, :user_departments], :group => []}]
```

How would you go about go about putting the include in for when you are searching multiple models?

This is an example of a Single one:

```
Event.search(:include => [:user]) do...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sunspot rails: include associated models when calling .results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282344/sunspot-rails-include-associated-models-when-calling-results)

Comment: Yeah in the question i say it similar. What i am asking is how to include it in the block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this solution works for me :

```
search_in = [Post, Tweet]
search = Sunspot.search search_in do
    search_in.each{|m|data_accessor_for(m).include = [:user]}
    [...]
end
```

Hope this solution help.

Have a nice day :)